# referencing variable cells within the AVERAGE function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to create an automated system to average data, but the starting row and ending row of that data varies from one time to the next.  I currently use the LOOKUP function to locate a reference value in one column as my starting point in another column and a second LOOKUP function to find my ending point in the one column to find my ending reference point for the AVERAGE function.  But I can not figure out how to pull the starting cell and ending cell reference points into the AVERAGE function?

I have tried using the MATCH function to see the row number for both the starting and ending points, but again I can't seem to pull those into the AVERAGE function to specify the starting and ending cells for use by the AVERAGE function.  I have also looked at the INPUT function, but that will only allow me to access the values of those two specific cells and not the entire range of cells between the starting and ending point.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can use `OFFSET()`.

Answer (score 2):

If your "start" and "end" have some relationship to each other (like dates) and they are in order you can use `AVERAGEIF` or `AVERAGEIFS`. This is useful for sales or other figures over a date range from a list. For example:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B2:B18,A2:A18,">="&F1,A2:A18,"<="&F2)
```

[image: Screenshot of an example]

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

If we want the *AVERAGE()* of column **B** between **start** and **end**, we can use the *INDIRECT()* function:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B" & MATCH("start",A:A,0) & ":" & "B" & MATCH("end",A:A,0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but due to the nature of the data, neither of these will work as the data does is not that easily defined as to where the start and end points are and are not always at a relative location to one another (we are trying to average a vacuum level over a temperature range, with the temperature varying in a somewhat inconsistent way while within that range).